# Some Combobox returns system.data.datarow while other returns correctly why

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

The below is the code which returns correctly in one form,

```
private void LoadCompanyNames()
        {
            ds = dataconnector.GetCompanyNames();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            statlbl.Text = "Retrieving Company Details";
            cmpycb.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
            cmpycb.ValueMember = "CompanyID";
            cmpycb.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

but, in second form when i called it returns **system.data.datarowview** 
code in second form

```
private void LoadCompanyNames()
{
            ds2 = dataconnector.GetCompanyNames();
            dt2 = ds.Tables[0];
            statlbl.Text = "Retrieving Company Details";
            regnamcb.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
            regnamcb.ValueMember = "CompanyID";
            regnamcb.DataSource = dt2;
}
```

Also, i checked the property of both the combobox in both forms, it looks similar.

If anyone knows the cause, thanks for their help.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns system.data.datarowview"?

Comment: In the combobox items, it returns System.data.datarowview as three times rather than displaying the items in the dropdown.

Comment: It looks like you are resetting the `regnamcb.DisplayMember` value somewhere else.

Comment: Where are you trying to get the combobox selected value?

Comment: Thanks Romanoza, but i dont made any such reset in my code and i put **regnamcb.enabled = true** only in form load.

Comment: @Alex. Thanks Alex for the reply,In second form, i had combobox named "regnamcb" and i wants it to return value as one behave in first form.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value in `selectedindex_changed` event or `form_load` or ... ? Please clarify your quetion.

Comment: @Alex. I am trying to get this at form_load on both forms.

Comment: @Alex. Actually I can't understand is "for the first form it works when i called from the form_load but for the second form it is not working even everything seems to be same."

Comment: @Alex, thanks it works....

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the `System.Data.DataRowView` as the value because the ComboBox still hasn't been loaded. I suggest put the code in some other events like `form_shown`.

Also you can check whether the value its loaded by checking selected value like this:

```
if (combobox.SelectedValue == null || 
             combobox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "System.Data.DataRowView")
      return;
      //Rest of the code
```